# Postgres: difference between CTE and temporary table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

In Postgres is there a difference between a CTE and a temporary table other than the fact that the CTE exists just for the context of one statement?

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) says that

> Common Table Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables that exist just for one query.

Does "can be thought" means that they are identical?

Comment: Not identical because a CTE is not necessarily written to disk

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- one can imagine circumstances where a temporary table is never written to disk as well.

Comment: I was asking specifically in the context of Postgres. This blog post makes me think that CTE's in Postgres are always materialised:

http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Answer (score 4):

A CTE is just that -- Common Table *Expression*, that is, only a syntax construct. The result set described by a CTE may never be materialized in the specified form.

A temporary table, on the other hand, is a real database object that is initialized with the structure described by its DDL statement and possibly populated by actual rows.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what others have said. Temporary tables can also have primary keys, constraints, indexes, etc. whereas CTEs cannot.

On the flip side, you can do some pretty neat tricks with CTEs that would be harder, I think, if done with temporary tables-- such as chaining them to perform deletes, inserts, and selects all in one statement. There are some nice examples of "cool-CTE-tricks" [here](http://engineering.tilt.com/7-postgresql-data-migration-hacks/).